# Scroll to bottom in predefined period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is it possible to scroll from the top of the page to the bottom with javascript in a predefined period of time? So it takes exactly, let's say, 90 seconds?

I tried this, but the scrolling takes about 6 seconds, not 10, as I specified.

```
$('body,html')
    .animate({
        scrollTop: ($("body")
            .height() + $(window)
            .height())
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: "linear"
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But, should we code it all for you? Or what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the bottom solution, but it does not seem to scroll exactly 10 seconds, but about 6.

Comment: I was talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: As I said, I tried the solution I put below, but the timing is not right. I think the code below is reproducable?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is the way, but you need to use the height of the document, since `$("body")` height and `$(window)` height are slightly different.

The actual height you are searching for, is the height of the `document`:

```
$('body,html')
    .animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: "linear"
    });
```

By doing `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` you remove the extra scroll offset when the scroll is already at the bottom of the document.

**See it working here:** *This example has enough proof that the time you specify to the duration is the time it takes to scroll to the bottom.*

```js
var init = new Date();
var lastDate = false;

$('#go').click(function() {
  init = new Date(); //When the scroll started
  $("body,html")
    .animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() //Bottom scroll integer
    }, {
      easing: "linear",
      duration: 10000
    });
});



//Event that handles when the scroll is at the bottom
$(window)
  .on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
      // when scroll to bottom of the page
      lastDate = new Date();
      console.log("Seconds: " + parseFloat((lastDate - init) / 1000));
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#go {
  position: fixed;
  right: 150px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Click</button>1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4
<br> 5
<br> 6
<br> 7
<br> 8
<br> 9
<br> 10
<br>
```

***Note:*** If for some reason you are not receiving the expected behavior, there might be something else causing conflict in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The animation is still too fast, about half the time (4-5 seconds, not 10)

Comment: @AlesSvetina take a look again, I edited it with enough proof that my answer is the code you need and works. Might be something else causing this issue in your code?